# Jenkins - Git plugin is not creating local subdirectory for repo when started by CI

Tags: git, unix, continuous-integration, jenkins

I have Jenkins setup using git and use a github hook for continuous integration.  I'm using a custom workspace directory.  Under source code management, I use Git.  I'm only checking out the master branch and I have $GIT_BRANCH-$GIT_COMMIT as my directory location in the "Local subdirectory for repo (optional)" field.  In the build section, I'm executing a shell, where I'm performing:

```
- pwd
- ls
- cd $GIT_BRANCH-$GIT_COMMIT
- ...
```

The problem I'm getting is when performing, "cd $GIT_BRANCH-$GIT_COMMIT."  I receive the following error:

```
- /tmp/hudson7624299777846840848.sh: 4: cd: can't cd to master-9297429dba145737291168f284796421f73c0ee3
```

Per pwd, I'm in the correct directory.  `ls` does not show the directory as being created, which is why I receive this error.  After the build has failed, I have checked the build host to see if the clone has been performed and directory has been created.  It appears to have not.  However, when I execute the build manually, the build passes.  `ls` shows the directory.

Any insight here of why this occurs would be greatly appreciated. My goal here is to create a new directory with the latest source for every build so I can maintain a history of tests, metrics, etc.  I'm new to Jenkins, so if there is a better way to do this I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What Jenkins version are you using? (thereis a current bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11337). And did you try to add in your shell a `mkdir $GIT_BRANCH-$GIT_COMMIT`?

Comment: @VonC, I'm on version 1.483. `mkdir $GIT_BRANCH-$GIT_COMMIT` works in shell, but unfortunately, code has not been checked out.  So the environment variables work appropriately, but it appears the initial clone fails and I'm not seeing any errors in logs.

Comment: Then can you try and add in your shell the git clone itself, just to see if it works that way?

Comment: That would probably work, but would $GIT_BRANCH and $GIT_COMMIT be available since I'm no longer using the git plugin? Or would I manually have to set those?

Comment: Yes, you would have to set those variable manually (just for this test), since there are from the git plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/434/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables can be resolved using the following syntax within the custom workspace directory field

```
${GIT_BRANCH}-${GIT_COMMIT}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This actually solved my problem.  I'm actually not sure why I was getting my initial issue.  My theory is it has something to do with the "Local subdirectory for repo" field in the GIT plugin.  However, by using the above, I was not only able to bypass using that field and but also satisfy my original intention (a unique workspace for every build).

Answer (score 0):

I previously hit a similar problem.  My attempts to use a Linux command alias within the 'custom workspace directory' field was not successful.

I'll highlight a secondary option:
If archiving is required, you can specify ./recent as the workspace directory and to add a series of post-build commands.  For example:

```
MMMDD=`date +%b%d`
cp -R ./recent ./$MMMDD
```